# Finding size of files locally/remotely

Tags: java, php, file, curl, jsoup

I'm writing a program to find the file size of files.

Is it possible in java?

In PHP I know there is a filesize().

Another alternative was using ab http:// in unix but how is it integratabtle with java?

What do you think is the best/most efficient way to attack this?

Comment: *"and all the content on the page"* Including the content embedded using JS?

Comment: This task is better suited to a dynamic and/or scripting language. It'll be a cinch with Ruby/bash/gnu tools.

Comment: How exactly is Jsoup related to this?

Comment: I figured it out using java and working with URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use java Runtime to execute the command and read the output from the buffer and display it.

```
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec("ab http://whatever ");
        // read the stream into the buffer and display the results.
```

If you have the file locally, then you can use File.length()

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve a page, extract links, and then only request the header for each uri.

filesize() in PHP may be dicey, as whether or not you're allowed to use it on a remote file will be entirely up to the configuration of your host. You might consider curl instead

Using curl from a shell, for instance, to look at an ad on the rhs of the page as I write this:

```
 curl -I http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/180414077f314dbdbaa8d8e2f7898249.gif
```

...yields, among other things:

```
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Length: 17798
```

...which may be what you're looking for. Within PHP, get the equivalent with [CURLOPT_NOBODY](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)